# Recuperar campo Json 2 nivel de array gson o Jackson

Tags: java, gson, jackson

Tengo un Json con el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "resultado": [
    {
      "columa": [
        "p"
      ],
      "datos": [
        {
          "row": [
            {
              "oficina": "0000",
              "entidad": "1234",
              "nombre": "nombre persona"
            }
          ],
          "meta": [
            {
              "id": 4700925,
              "type": "node",
              "deleted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": [],
  "responseTime": 84
}
```

¿Cómo puedo recuperar el dato oficina y entidad?

Comment: Ese Json está bien formado??? Compruebalo en https://jsonlint.com/ que creo que tiene algún fallo

Comment: Corregido Json, se me escapó una parte al editarlo. Gracias @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto recuperas los 2 campos que quieres:

```
String t = "{ \"resultado\": [{\"columa\": [\"p\"],\"datos\": [{\"row\": [{\"oficina\": \"0000\",\"entidad\": \"1234\"," +
            "\"nombre\": \"nombre persona\"}],\"meta\": [{\"id\": 4700925,\"type\": \"node\",\"deleted\": false}]}]}],\"errors\": [],\"responseTime\": 84}\"" ;

    JSONObject js = null;

    String oficina="";
    String entidad="";

    try {
        js = new JSONObject(t);
        JSONArray res = (JSONArray) js.get("resultado");

        JSONObject jsDat = (JSONObject) res.get(0);

        JSONArray jsDatArr = (JSONArray) jsDat.getJSONArray("datos");

        JSONObject jsRow = (JSONObject) jsDatArr.get(0);

        JSONArray jsRowArr = (JSONArray) jsRow.get("row");

        JSONObject jsFin = (JSONObject) jsRowArr.get(0);

        oficina = jsFin.getString("oficina");
        entidad = jsFin.getString("entidad");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.Info(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Con esto funciona aunque no quede muy elegante, al tener varios niveles toca ir recorriendo uno por uno.

Si necesitas tener acceso a todos los datos te recomendaría que te creases tu objeto resultado para deserializar el JSon en un objeto, es mucho mas sencillo para recorrerlo después, pero si sólo quieres esos 2 datos con ese código los sacas.